# Perl module: break date interval into sub intervals?

Tags: perl, date, datetime, intervals

Lets say I have:

```
dateA : sometime in the past(ex: 2013-01-01T00:00:00)(yyyy-mm-dd)
dateB :now
intervalLength: from dateA - now
```

If the interval length greater than 30 days i need to generate an array where each position would hold an object with start and end of every subinterval:

```
intervalLength[0]: {start:2013-01-01T00:00:00, end:2013-01-30T00:00:00}
intervalLength[1]: {start:2013-01-30T00:00:01, end:2013-02-28T00:00:00}
...
intervalLength[n]: "last interval/rest" < 30days
```

So basically I need a module that can break a date interval into smaller sub intervals. Ideally a method which I can call by passing 2 dates and required interval max length as arguments.

Comment: And so far you have tryed...?

Comment: @JohnDoe  What you mean? I am asking for a reference to a module. Point is not having to write the solution from scratch as I´d worry about exception cases... What I have tried is searching at cpanm unsuccessfully...

Comment: Because most of the times, this kind of question will be flagged as off-topic for `requesting a library suggestion`.

Comment: So you don't want an actual interval (as in a _duration_), but you want your interval to be represented by two dates. One is the start and one is the end. And they should always be to the end of a month, so you have several if the interval is across multiple months. There is no ready module for that, but I would think that DateTime is best suited to build this. Also, do you care about the time at all? Because the end would be `2013-01-30T23:59:59` and not `2013-01-30T00:00:00` (assuming where you live January only has 30 days of course). :)

Comment: @simbabque interval represented by two dates true. Not to end of month, end date should always be start date(whatever it may be) + 30 days. Reason for this is that Moves App API limits you to request at most 31 days of data at once(per server call). So I am creating a script that runs every day at 00:00:00 that pulls new data from the API. The first time this happens for a given user the data might exist on Moves API since over a year ago so I have to break down the server petions.

Comment: But you would get `2013-01-30` twice in the example above, right?

Comment: yes you are right about that

Comment: `DateTime` module will work for this, If you just needs to breakdown the date time part.

Comment: Can you give a few examples for testing? I think I've got a solution, but I'd like some more tests.

Comment: What kind of example, data?

Comment: https://dev.moves-app.com/docs/api_summaries

Comment: https://dev.moves-app.com/docs/api_profile

Comment: Date1 is what is reflected in user profile and Date2 would be now/when script runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime) and [DateTime::Duration](http://p3rl.org/DateTime::Duration), but it should be easy to implement with [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) as well. The point is that you need to do the calculating yourself.

```
sub get_interval {
    my ( $start, $end ) = @_;

    # to get a 30 day timespan we need to add 29
    # 01. to 30. = 1 + 29
    my $twenty_nine_days = DateTime::Duration->new( days => 29 );

    my @return;
    while ( ( my $step = $start + $twenty_nine_days ) < $end ) {
        push @return, { start => $start->ymd, end => $step->ymd };
        $start = $step;
    }
    push @return, { start => $start->ymd, end => $end->ymd };

    return \@return;
}
```

This function takes two DateTime objects and returns a structure similar to the example you showed. It works by adding 29 days to the start date in a loop until the end date is exceeded.

We need to use 29 days and not 30 days because we want an interval of 30 days, but the start date is already the first day, so it's 29.

Let's try with this call:

```
use Data::Printer;
p get_interval(
    DateTime->new( year => 2016, month => 1,  day => 1 ),
    DateTime->new( year => 2016, month => 12, day => 8 )
);
```

And the output using [Data::Printer](http://p3rl.org/Data::Printer):

```
\ [
    [0]  {
        end     "2016-01-30",
        start   "2016-01-01"
    },
    [1]  {
        end     "2016-02-28",
        start   "2016-01-30"
    },
    [2]  {
        end     "2016-03-28",
        start   "2016-02-28"
    },
    [3]  {
        end     "2016-04-26",
        start   "2016-03-28"
    },
    [4]  {
        end     "2016-05-25",
        start   "2016-04-26"
    },
    [5]  {
        end     "2016-06-23",
        start   "2016-05-25"
    },
    [6]  {
        end     "2016-07-22",
        start   "2016-06-23"
    },
    [7]  {
        end     "2016-08-20",
        start   "2016-07-22"
    },
    [8]  {
        end     "2016-09-18",
        start   "2016-08-20"
    },
    [9]  {
        end     "2016-10-17",
        start   "2016-09-18"
    },
    [10] {
        end     "2016-11-15",
        start   "2016-10-17"
    },
    [11] {
        end     "2016-12-08",
        start   "2016-11-15"
    }
]
```

I've written some unit tests as well. They are by no means complete, but they give a good starting point.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Printer;
use Test::More;
use Test::Deep;
use DateTime;

sub get_date {
    my ( $year, $month, $day ) = @_;
    return DateTime->new( year => $year, month => $month, day => $day );
}

cmp_deeply get_interval( get_date( 2013, 1, 1 ), get_date( 2013, 2, 20 ) ),
  [
    { start => '2013-01-01', end => '2013-01-30', },
    { start => '2013-01-30', end => '2013-02-20', },
  ],
  'one and a bit intervals';

cmp_deeply get_interval( get_date( 2013, 1, 5 ), get_date( 2013, 1, 7 ) ),
  [ { start => '2013-01-05', end => '2013-01-07', }, ],
  'three days in one month';

cmp_deeply get_interval( get_date( 2013, 1, 30 ), get_date( 2013, 2, 1 ) ),
  [ { start => '2013-01-30', end => '2013-02-01', }, ],
  'three days over two month';

cmp_deeply get_interval( get_date( 2013, 1, 01 ), get_date( 2014, 1, 31 ) ),
  [
    { start => '2013-01-01', end => '2013-01-30', },
    { start => '2013-01-30', end => '2013-02-28', },
    { start => '2013-02-28', end => '2013-03-29', },
    { start => '2013-03-29', end => '2013-04-27', },
    { start => '2013-04-27', end => '2013-05-26', },
    { start => '2013-05-26', end => '2013-06-24', },
    { start => '2013-06-24', end => '2013-07-23', },
    { start => '2013-07-23', end => '2013-08-21', },
    { start => '2013-08-21', end => '2013-09-19', },
    { start => '2013-09-19', end => '2013-10-18', },
    { start => '2013-10-18', end => '2013-11-16', },
    { start => '2013-11-16', end => '2013-12-15', },
    { start => '2013-12-15', end => '2014-01-13', },
    { start => '2014-01-13', end => '2014-01-31', },
  ],
  'three days over two month';

# what happens if start > end?

done_testing;

sub get_interval {
    my ( $start, $end ) = @_;

    # to get a 30 day timespan we need to add 29
    # 01. to 30. = 1 + 29
    my $twenty_nine_days = DateTime::Duration->new( days => 29 );

    my @return;
    while ( ( my $step = $start + $twenty_nine_days ) < $end ) {
        push @return, { start => $start->ymd, end => $step->ymd };
        $start = $step;
    }
    push @return, { start => $start->ymd, end => $end->ymd };

    return \@return;
}
```

Comment: wow, I was happy with a reference to a module :) and you built this nice sub. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @AlExTsm well, I am bored. :P